# PHP pages load, but also show the raw code with them in chrome browser

Tags: php, web

I am new to PHP, and I am having a bit of an issue.

My .php files, which I code in Netbeans 7.3, work fine when I run them through the IDE's compiler. But the same web pages show the raw code, **along** when I run them in my Google Chrome browser.

Here is a sample code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title> Add Your Highscore! </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> Guitar Wars - Add you highscore!</h2>
        <?php
        //echo "successful!!";


        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $score=$_POST['score'];
        $screenshot=$_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
        $screenshot_type=$_FILES['screenshot']['type'];
        $screenshot_size=$_FILES['screenshot']['size'];

        $output=false;
        if(!empty($name)&&!!empty($score)&&!empty($screenshot))
       {  

            if ((($screenshot_type == 'image/gif') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($screenshot_type == 'image/png'))
        && ($screenshot_size > 0) && ($screenshot_size <= GW_MAXFILESIZE)) {
        if ($_FILES['screenshot']['error'] == 0) {
          // Move the file to the target upload folder
          $target = 'images' . $screenshot;
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
            // Connect to the database
         {
            $db=  mysqli_connect('localhost','root', 'akash123','gwdb') 

                  or die('Error in connecting to the database');
        //echo "</br> successful connection";
        $query= "insert into guitar wars values(0,NOW(),$name, $score, $screenshot ";
        //echo "</br> successful query";
        $result= mysqli_query($db,$query) ;

       mysqli_close($db,$query);
       echo "</br> Successful!";
       $name='';
       $score='';
       $screenshot='';

        mysqli_close($db);
        }
        else
        {echo "There was a problem uploading the image";
        }

        }  
        else
        {echo "There was a problem uploading the image";

        $output=true;
        }
        }


        else{echo '<p class="error">The screen shot must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no greater than ' . (GW_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) . ' KB in size.</p>';
        $output=true;
        }}

        else{echo "* Enter all the information to add your highscore";
        $output=true;
        }

        }

        else
        { 
            $output=true;
            $name='';
            $score='';
        }

            if ($output){ 
            ?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="65536"/>
<label for="name">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name"  name="name" value="<?php echo $name ; ?>" /></br>
<label for="score">Your Highscore :</label>
<input type="text" id="score"  name="score" value="<?php echo $score ; ?>" /></br>
<label for="screenshot"> Screenshot of your Highscore: </label>
<input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot" /></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>

</form>
    <?php

        }


        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Internet Explorer is hopeless, as it tries to downloads the .php file.

What is the reason of this outcome?

Comment: Are you using apache or IIS?

Comment: Your php code isn't being compiled by the webserver it has nothing to do with the browser

Comment: If you're loading them locally you need to setup a web server that will compile the code prior to display.

Comment: are you using a webserver at all, or just throwing the PHP file to the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot "open" a php file in a browser, you have to "run" it. netbeans will run files (note they don't get compiled in the way things like java get compiled)

if you are testing on your local machine, you need an apache installation which runs php ([xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for example).

if you are using xampp:

open the htdocs folder inside the xampp folder.

create a new folder for your webapp.

put your php file in that folder.

in your web browser, NAVIGATE to your php page (in the address bar, type in the IP address of the machine running xampp, or localhost, or however you have it configured, mylocalhostip/mywebapp/myphpfile.php for example.

then it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver is probably not passing the file to a PHP interpreter. Check your webserver configuration.